# AWS GLUE ETL - How concat values in new column

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to concatenate a new column in Glue ETL but there is an error that I do not understand how to solve. Error is occurring in this snippet `datasource2 = DynamicFrame (datasource1, glueContext)`

Error:

```
line 25 datasource2 = DynamicFrame(datasource1, glueContext) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "runscript3.py", line 86, in <module> while "runpy.py" in new_stack.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'
```

Code

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "rawdata", table_name = "postalcode", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

datasource1 = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("adressjoin", concat(col("streettype"), col("street"))
datasource2 = DynamicFrame(datasource1, glueContext)

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource2, mappings = [("adressjoin", "string", "adressjoin", "string"), ("streettype", "string", "streettype", "string"), ("street", "string", "street", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")

dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://mys3_566757/newtable"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Comment: A simple syntaxerror: you forgot the closing parenthesis on the line `datasource1 = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("adressjoin", concat(col("streettype"), col("street"))`

Comment: I had not imported a col class, I made this change and it worked. datasource1 = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("adressjoin", concat(datasource0["streettype"], datasource0["street"])

Comment: `DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource1, glueContext, "datasource2")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to solve the error in pyspark(convert dynamic frame to dataframe)

change

```
datasource2 = DynamicFrame(datasource1, glueContext) //it will work on scala spark
```

To

```
datasource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource1, glueContext, datasource2)
```